# How to wire an entire room / kitchen with LED light strips?

Tags: led, safety, wiring, led-strip

As the question suggests, I'm looking into adding LED light strips throughout the kitchen (over cabinet, under cabinet, and kick -- I think under the countertop would be neat, but harder to hide). From what I have been reading, I realize that to more accurately determine what is needed that I would need to know specifics about the lights (like wattage, amperage, run lengths, LEDs per foot/meter).

But without knowing those specifics yet, to try to better understand how feasible this is, here is my intended setup. The kitchen has cabinets on opposite walls, with an island in the middle, something like this (where the square brackets represent cabinets and the island):

```
[]  []  []
[]  []  []
[]  []  []
[]______[]
```

Is it possible to have everything wired together on one circuit, even though there's about 15' from one side of the kitchen to the other? Am I able to run a wire (maybe 16/5 -- thinking of using RGBW) under the floor/ceiling to get to the other side and then hook up the strips without worrying about voltage drop? I'm sure this is possible, I just don't want to spend a fortune to make it work.

As a side question, if anyone knows, is there such thing as a on/off/motion switch, that also works with wifi (for use with Google Assistant / Alexa)? The thought would be I could turn the lights on or off, or to a motion mode that detects presence in the room.

Comment: What kind of LED strips are you going to use, specifically, how many Watts per meter and how long should the strips be in total? This will dictate what power supply you will need for the strips. I don't think you will have to worry about voltage drop since usually those strips are wired up in parallel.

Comment: Perhaps better on the Homeimprovement stack ie DIY

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for DIY

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Is there a way to transfer this question over? Or just copy-paste?